# check in a string php

Tags: php

I have a string and it can contain values like this
$string = '1,2,3,4,5';
I wanna put a check that will see if the string contains 4 or 5
if it contains 4 or 5 then I want to echo success
otherwise if it contains 9 or 10 I wanna echo fail

I know there is a n in_array function but not sure how to use it
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test for the number 4 like this:

```
if(in_array('4', explode(',', $string))) echo "it's in there";
```

or just by string searching:

```
if(strpos(',4,', ','.$string.',') !== false) echo "it's in there";
```

Comment: to expand on Scott's answer a little, typically you'd always use a string function to check for string comparisons, strpos is one option - note he's used a strong !== FALSE as a simple != FALSE would also be true for 0 which is a valid string offset (if 4 or 5 was the first char in the string 0 would be returned) - also worth noting that many have also given in_array responses purely because you mentioned it, and because in this specific case you can explode on the comma to get an array, typically we'd stick to the string functions for this.

Answer (score 1):

in_array won't help you here because you have a string, not an array. What you're looking for is the strpos() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Note that if it doesn't find what it's looking for in your string, it'll return false on its own, so all you have to do is check whether it returns a result or not to meet your conditions.

Comment: No, `strpos` will not work in OP:s case. With `49` in the string the outcome would be both true and false.

Comment: `strpos` can work if used correctly (see Scott Saunders' answer)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `strpos()` to check for the existence of a substring inside a string, like this:

```
if(strpos(','.$string.',', ','.$number_to_check_for.',') !== false) {
    //success, substring was found
} else {
    //error, substring was not found.
}
```

or you could explode it into an array then use `in_array()`:

```
$array = explode(',',$string);

if(in_array($number_to_check_for, $array)) {
    //success substring found
} else {
    //error, substring not found
}
```

But I would recommend the first solution, as it is cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Your strpos() example will fail if the $string can contain 4, 14 and 41

Answer (score 1):

```
$set = array (1,2,3...,n); //you can use range() function if the numbers going one by one or explode if you have a string
if(in_array($var,$set))
{
   Echo 'IS in ARRAY!';
} else {
   Echo 'fail';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$goodString = '1,2,3,4,5';
$badString = '1,2,3,7,8,9,10';

function checkString($str) {
    $arr = explode(',', $str);
    $message = 'no message';
    if (
        in_array(4, $arr)||
        in_array(5, $arr)
    ) {
        $message = 'success';
    } else if (
        in_array(9, $arr)||
        in_array(10, $arr)
    ) {
        $message = 'fail';
    }
    echo $message;
}

checkString($goodString); // prints success
checkString($badString); // prints fail
```

Answer (score 1):

Check all at once :)

`if(in_array(array(4,5), explode(',', $string))) echo "success";`

`if(in_array(array(9,10), explode(',', $string))) echo "failure";`